# Libgdx | Load assets in ApplicationAdapter createor each screen's show method?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, desktop

I'm going to create an assetManager in my ApplicationAdapter class, that will be responsible of loading all assets. I'm wondering whether loading the assets in the ApplicationAdapter's create method where the assetManager is located would be best? Would it also be alright to dispose of the assetManager and all of it's contents in the ApplicationAdapter's dispose method? I'm not sure whether there will be any memory leaks caused by users exiting the app or whatnot. Thanks!

Comment: That will work fine.

Comment: @Tenfour04 So, no need to load anything in each show method in each screen? And I don't need to use the dispose methods in each screen?

Comment: No, you don't even have to use Screens. I don't. You only need to be sure anything that's loaded is disposed by the time the game closes. The dispose method in your ApplicationAdapter is your last chance to do that.

Comment: @Tenfour04  What do you use instead of screens? Your own implementation of something similar?